# List view filter

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, filter

Can I filter my view to show only 5000 recent added/updated out of 6000 items?
My list has more than 5000 items and I want to show only 5000 recent items.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this,

First you have to Sort items by modified date or Created date and then set item limit.

1. Go to "Your View" In list setting.
2. Click on "Your View" on which you want to set item limits. (Modify View)
3. In "Sort" section, select "created" or "modified" column from drop down.
4. Then select the radio button "Show items in descending order"
5. Go down, In "Item Limit" section, Type the maximum number of items you want to display.
6. Then select radio button "Limit the total number of items returned to the specified amount".
7. Ok

Comment: but pagination wouldn't work, I want paging as well.

Comment: Then there is another radio button  under "item limit" section  "Display items in a batch of specified size" . Select this. It will enable pagination.

Comment: "Item Limit" section, Type the maximum number of items you want to display. gives the number of items you want to display per page, I am looking for an option to show only 5000 items but with pagination.

Comment: As I told in my comment. Select radio button  "Display items in a batch of specified size"

Comment: but that will throw error if items are more than 5000.

Comment: list view thrash hold limit is 5000 & May be this causes the error. What error you got?

Comment: yes i am getting threashold error, see my original question, I have more than 6000 items and I want to show 5000 most recent.